# Chainlink UpKeep Registration ABI Error Problem

Tags: solidity, javascript, abi, chainlink, deployed-bytecode

Everytime I try to register my UpKeep on Chainlink Automation, I get this error, "ABI must be of type { "name": string, "inputs": { "name": string, "type": string }[] }[]".

The ABI is,

```
[
    {
      "inputs": [],
      "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
      "type": "constructor"
    },
    {
      "stateMutability": "payable",
      "type": "fallback"
    },
    {
      "inputs": [],
      "name": "getAmpleforthPrice",
      "outputs": [
        {
          "internalType": "int256",
          "name": "",
          "type": "int256"
        },
        {
          "internalType": "int256",
          "name": "",
          "type": "int256"
        }
      ],
      "stateMutability": "view",
      "type": "function"
    },
    {
      "inputs": [],
      "name": "getBitcoinPrice",
      "outputs": [
        {
          "internalType": "int256",
          "name": "",
          "type": "int256"
        },
        {
          "internalType": "int256",
          "name": "",
          "type": "int256"
        }
      ],
      "stateMutability": "view",
      "type": "function"
    },
    {
      "inputs": [],
      "name": "getBritishPoundPrice",
      "outputs": [
        {
          "internalType": "int256",
          "name": "",
          "type": "int256"
        },
        {
          "internalType": "uint8",
          "name": "",
          "type": "uint8"
        }
      ],
      "stateMutability": "view",
      "type": "function"
    },
    {
      "inputs": [],
      "name": "getChainlinkPrice",
      "outputs": [
        {
          "internalType": "int256",
          "name": "",
          "type": "int256"
        },
        {
          "internalType": "int256",
          "name": "",
          "type": "int256"
        }
      ],
      "stateMutability": "view",
      "type": "function"
    },
    {
      "inputs": [],
      "name": "getEtherPrice",
      "outputs": [
        {
          "internalType": "int256",
          "name": "",
          "type": "int256"
        },
        {
          "internalType": "int256",
          "name": "",
          "type": "int256"
        }
      ],
      "stateMutability": "view",
      "type": "function"
    },
    {
      "inputs": [],
      "name": "getEuroPrice",
      "outputs": [
        {
          "internalType": "int256",
          "name": "",
          "type": "int256"
        },
        {
          "internalType": "uint8",
          "name": "",
          "type": "uint8"
        }
      ],
      "stateMutability": "view",
      "type": "function"
    },
    {
      "inputs": [],
      "name": "getGoldPrice",
      "outputs": [
        {
          "internalType": "int256",
          "name": "",
          "type": "int256"
        },
        {
          "internalType": "int256",
          "name": "",
          "type": "int256"
        }
      ],
      "stateMutability": "view",
      "type": "function"
    },
    {
      "inputs": [],
      "name": "getKorunaPrice",
      "outputs": [
        {
          "internalType": "int256",
          "name": "",
          "type": "int256"
        },
        {
          "internalType": "uint8",
          "name": "",
          "type": "uint8"
        }
      ],
      "stateMutability": "view",
      "type": "function"
    },
    {
      "inputs": [],
      "name": "getStakeStarPoR",
      "outputs": [
        {
          "internalType": "int256",
          "name": "",
          "type": "int256"
        },
        {
          "internalType": "int256",
          "name": "",
          "type": "int256"
        }
      ],
      "stateMutability": "view",
      "type": "function"
    },
    {
      "inputs": [],
      "name": "getSynnexPrice",
      "outputs": [
        {
          "internalType": "int256",
          "name": "",
          "type": "int256"
        },
        {
          "internalType": "uint8",
          "name": "",
          "type": "uint8"
        }
      ],
      "stateMutability": "view",
      "type": "function"
    },
    {
      "inputs": [],
      "name": "getYenPrice",
      "outputs": [
        {
          "internalType": "int256",
          "name": "",
          "type": "int256"
        },
        {
          "internalType": "uint8",
          "name": "",
          "type": "uint8"
        }
      ],
      "stateMutability": "view",
      "type": "function"
    },
    {
      "stateMutability": "payable",
      "type": "receive"
    }
  ]
```

Please, can anyone help?

Comment: Hi Vidhan, can you edit your question and share the solidity code of your contract?

Answer (score 0):

I converted your ABI file to an interface and find all functions in the interface are `view` functions, which means that no state will be modified when these functions are called. Solidity codes are shown below:

```
interface GeneratedInterface {
  function getAmpleforthPrice (  ) external view returns ( int256, int256 );
  function getBitcoinPrice (  ) external view returns ( int256, int256 );
  function getBritishPoundPrice (  ) external view returns ( int256, uint8 );
  function getChainlinkPrice (  ) external view returns ( int256, int256 );
  function getEtherPrice (  ) external view returns ( int256, int256 );
  function getEuroPrice (  ) external view returns ( int256, uint8 );
  function getGoldPrice (  ) external view returns ( int256, int256 );
  function getKorunaPrice (  ) external view returns ( int256, uint8 );
  function getStakeStarPoR (  ) external view returns ( int256, int256 );
  function getSynnexPrice (  ) external view returns ( int256, uint8 );
  function getYenPrice (  ) external view returns ( int256, uint8 );
}
```

Chainlink automation is not designed to call `view` functions. Try to add a non `view` functions in your contract and you can go to next step.

If you have any use case where `view` functions are supposed to be called by Chainlink automation, please share the use case and we can see how to design the process.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error while attempting to register a time-based keeper for a proxy contract. The issue lies in the fact that the ABI cannot be automatically verified, necessitating manual provision.
Specifically, I encountered the error when compiling with the ABI of the `TransparentUpgradeableProxy` contract.

The specific error message is as follows:

> 

```
"ABI must be of type { 'name': string, 'inputs': { 'name': string,
> 'type': string }[] }[]."
```

Here are the addresses for the smart contracts that I have hosted on Sepolia:

- **`Proxy Admin`**: 0x4f64157434aaA2296dc9F6c7199bc5D0a129B417
- **`Implementation`**: 0x158fa258C8715C5A3bDb48ae8384972303e22353
- **`TransparentUpgradeableProxy`**: 0x8Df6700E99950991F73a7C5CE23bbEC6D8cC9dAB

Furthermore, I have included one of the Perform Upkeep transaction hashes for your reference: 0x5c433cdc2680ba0f82e5de42d6c5da01559a759d94055bd72bb90b4c0db3882a.

The answer is use **`Implementation` contract ABI** for the **`TransparentUpgradeableProxy` contract address**

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answering. You may want to specify that while this could be a useful answer for others experiencing this error, it doesn't seem to directly answer the OP's q since OP never mentions anything about a proxy and the ABI is not a proxy ABI.